# Prompt save as file doalog while saving worksheets as csv files

Tags: excel, csv, savefiledialog, vba

I have the following code to save my worksheets as csv files to the folder the workbook is saved in. How do I modify this to bring up a 'save as' dialog box to let me choose where I'd like to save?

To be more specific, I want to modify the code to be able to specify just the path to which all the files can be saved. I'm not looking to get a save as for each worksheet.

```
Sub SaveOnlyCSVsThatAreNeeded()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", ..."14 - User Defined Fields"))
    ws.Copy
    Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
    With newWb
      .SaveAs ws.Name, xlCSV
      .Close (False)
    End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have replaced the whole thing with a folder picker in an effort to simplify it. Posted updated code. Now I get Error code 9 - Subscript out of range.

```
Sub SaveOnlyCSVsThatAreNeeded()
Dim ws As Worksheet, newWb As Workbook
Dim pathh As Variant

Dim FolderName As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

pathh = FolderName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("01 - Currencies", "02 - .....14 - User Defined Fields"))
    ws.Copy
    Set newWb = ActiveWorkbook
    With newWb
      .SaveAs pathh.path & "\" & ws.Name, xlCSV
      .Close (False)
    End With
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to show the Save As dialog screen:

```
pathh = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
            FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
            Title:="Save all spreadsheets", _
            InitialFileName:=filenamestring)
```

Cheers

Comment: I guess i should rephrase. I want to modify the code so as to be able to specify just the path to which all the files can be saved to. I'm not looking to get a save as every time  for each and every worksheet.

Comment: You would have to code some type of folder selection form. I'm sure there are codes already made for this that you can find. Alternatively with `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` you can provide it options such as the `InitialFilename`. Then the user can just select the folder like a normal `Save As` dialogue and achieve your requirements. Could this not be a solution? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195734.aspx command documentation.

Comment: AlrightI have posted the modified code....but now it requires me to specify a filename and not just choose a path. What do I need to tweak to fix this?

Comment: You have to set the value of the filename using `InitialFilename` value in the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename`. Edited answer to represent further.

Comment: nbayly...I guess this makes senes..but this still forces me to specify a file name. I cant really specify a single file name as I am trying to save multiple sreadsheets as CSV files retaining their names in one shot

Comment: Yes but that filename doesn't have to be a static value. You can use a string variable as I have shown where you can determine each name from the previous document name or from anything you want. Just fill the variable name before calling the the Save As dialogue and the filename will autofill with what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I have replaced the whole thing with a folder picker in an effort to simplify it. Posted updated code. Now I get Error code 9 - Subscript out of range

Answer (score 0):

The command to propt the save as dialog in VB is:

```
Application.GetSaveAsFilename
```